# Orange Like Rusty Colored Blob in Toilet Tank

Tags: toilet

Is this orange blob iron? It was more intact before, but I poked at it and it began falling apart.
Coincidentally, the toilet suddenly started making popping sounds and flooding a lot underneath after flushing. I'm assuming that the wax seal or flange broke. Not sure if there's a correlation with the iron in the water in general and the seal going bad. Toilet is 7 yrs old with light use, does not rock. Water is city water. Water in the bowl is never orange.

[image]

Comment: if those were Stainless steal that would not happen

Answer (score 2):

Those are called toilet tank bolts.  They can wear out over time and can be replaced if everything else is in good condition.